# Adding init.d service (chkconfig / autocomplete in shell)

Tags: linux, service, autocomplete, zsh, system-administration

I've made a startup script, (i.e. myserviced) and put it in /etc/init.d/

I ran

```
chkconfig --add myserviced
```

I can start/stop/restart the service just find using:

```
service myserviced start
```

etc. However, I notice that when I type "service" and then do TAB (to get a list of possible completions), I don't see myserviced in the list of possible completions (it lists all the other services). How do I add myserviced to the auto-completion list?

This is in zsh on RHEL.

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, even if the file is not executable.  Try creating a pain file in /etc/init.d and see if it shows up in zsh tab completion.

Answer (score 15):

you can use the following command to add all listed scripts in `/etc/init.d/` to the service command:

```
complete -W "$(ls /etc/init.d/)" service
```

`-W` will create word list from the ($)specified path which 'service' will use for auto-complete.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `myserviced` is "executable." (i.e., `chmod +x /etc/init.d/myserviced`)

The completion lists all **executable** files in `/etc/init.d`, while `service` itself may work regardless of the permission.

Comment: the file is executable (and still doesn't show up in the tab completion of "service <TAB>")